# Asp.net core uiculture multiple threads

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In asp.net core, if i set the ui culture of a thread when user x calls my web service, can it cause other users to have their ui culture change? 
Explanation: i  read that a single thread can be used for multiple requests. is that true and if so how what happens when i change things like the ui culture?

also, if i use async await, can it cause another thread to come and "continue the work"? if so then setting the ui culture for a a request won't help me as later in the same request another thread can run and it's ui culture will be the default one

Comment: Are you doing something unusual and setting cultures yourself on threads? Why isn't the out-of-the-box localization enough in your case?

Comment: @juunas yes i am setting it myself. what should i do instead? i want to use strongly typed resources (code generated from the resx file)

Comment: Ah, that's certainly something the built-in localization doesn't seem to support :\